# How to have a good validation to check input is numeric

Tags: c++, validation, input, numeric, cin

I have seen several posts in SO asking for validation to check whether input is numeric. However there seems to have flaws in their proposed solutions.

Consider the following example for input of numbers:

```
for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
{
    cout << x+1 <<  ") Input a number: ";
    cin >> num;
    while (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(200, '\n');           
        cout << x+1 << ") Input a number: ";
        cin >> num; 
    }
    cout << "Your Number: " << num << endl;
}
```

**Sample Program Input/Output:**

```
1) Input a number: aaa a
1) Input a number: 50
Your Number: 50
2) Input a number: 3a b c 
Your Number: 3
3) Input a number: 3) Input a number:   <= How to prevent these duplicated prompts?
```

The codes I used above are acquired from some of the highest voted solutions in past SO posts. However if we give an alpha-numeric input, it will cause a duplicated prompt while prompting for the next input.

Note: The suggested solution is best to avoid functions from C++ 11.

**My question is:** How can we overcome this issue?

Comment: We can overcome it by writing a sufficient test suite.  We should explicitly write down all the cases we can think of for inputs, and their expected outputs.  Or use `boost::lexical_cast<>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a possible way to explictly prevent duplicated prompts.

```
for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
{
    cout << x+1 <<  ") Input a number: ";
    cin >> num;
    while (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(200, '\n');           
        cout << x+1 << ") Input a number: ";
        cin >> num;

    }
    cout << "Your Number: " << num << endl;
    cin.clear();              //Add this
    cin.ignore(200, '\n');    //and this
}
```

However this seems a little convoluted with too many `cin.clear()`, `cin.ignore()`. Still hopes someone could give their insightful solution.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to validate input is to test to make sure std:: cin doesn't set any flags, and then clear the buffer if it has.

I suggest that you use something like this ---

```
for ( ;; ) { 
    std:: cin << mph;
    if (! std:: cin.good () ) {
        std:: cerr << "Error! ";
        std:: cin.clear ();
        std:: cin.ignore (std:: numeric_limits 
            <std:: streamsize>:: max (), '\n');
    } else break;
}
```

The call to good () tells you whether or not std:: cin has encountered any error state. We only want to continue if it hasn't. And the call to clear () reset's cin's state flags, so that it's no longer in an error state. Similarly, ignore () flushes the buffer until it either reaches a newline, or the end of the stream (everything). That makes it so that the invalid data sitting in there is actually removed, so another try doesn't read that same data again, first, when you call operator<< again.

Personally, I tend to use this snippet:

```
template <class InputType>
void SafeInput (InputType & InputVar, std:: function <bool (InputType &)>
    Predicate) {
  for ( ;; ) {
    std:: cin >> InputVar;

    if (std:: cin.good () && Predicate (InputVar)) return;

    std:: cerr << "Input format error. Please Re-enter\n";

    std:: cin.clear ();
    std:: cin.ignore (std:: numeric_limits <std:: streamsize>:: max (), '\n');
  }
}
```

You are of course free to use that, if you so choose.

An example usage might be

```
std:: string TheStringToFill {};  
std:: cout << "\nYou may enter only the word \"cat\", but in any case.";
SafeInput <std:: string> (TheStringToFill,
            [] (std:: string Input) -> bool {
              std:: transform (Input.begin (), Input.end(),
                               Input.begin (), :: toupper);
              return (Input.compare ("CAT") == 0);
            } );
```

Or, better yet, using a number:

```
int TheValueToGetInputTo;  
std:: cout << "You may enter any number that is less then ten: ";
SafeInput <int> (TheValueToGetInputTo,
                 [=] (int Input) -> bool {
                   return Input < 10;
                 } );
```

You can of course replace any of the lambdas with named functions, but lambdas are smaller in this case.